# Runtime error before starting to execute GLEW code

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, glew

am setting up GLEW and GLFW on clion, glfw worked fine but I have a trouble with glew.
After linking glew, I built the code and worked fine, but when using any glew function then run the code, a runtime error shows up before executing any line code.

I tried deleting every glew file on my computer then reinstalling glew as proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667708/glew-run-time-linker-error) previous problem.
I thought the problem might be a linking problem so I searched for a proper way to link glew. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598323/how-to-properly-link-libraries-with-cmake) old question, but the glew version used in his case is different from the one I've downloaded from the official site which has Cmake ready to link.

Cmake code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(graphics)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(graphics main.cpp)

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(glfw)
target_link_libraries(graphics glfw)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(graphics OpenGL::GL)

add_subdirectory(glew-2.1.0/build/cmake)
target_link_libraries(graphics glew)
find_package(glew REQUIRED)
```

The code I try to run:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "glew-2.1.0/include/GL/glew.h"

int main()
{
    glewInit();
    return 0;
}
```

am still thinking it may be a linking problem but I don't have much experience with cmake.
hope you help me, thanks in advance

EDIT:
Problem fixed. It was a missed dll file. This file is glew32d.dll which created by clion after linking, but Clion couldn't use it so I put it in the project directory. I also tried to put in MinGW/bin and worked.
The program I used to figure out the missed dll file found in the comments.

Comment: ***still thinking it may be a linking problem*** No its not a linking problem, The error message `0xC0000135` means dll not found. Do you have the required dlls in one of the folders in your `PATH` environment variable? Or the same folder as your executable?

Comment: In [GLEW Documentation][http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html ], no mention about additional dll for static version, I tried to find out what could be required as additional files for static version but I didn't find any.
@drescherjm

Comment: This program should help you figure out what dll is needed: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. 
I used the program, glew32d.dll was missed.
This dll was created by Clion in **ProjectDir/cmake-build-debug/bin** , but Clion couldn't use it I don't know why, I tried to put with the project files and it worked.
@drescherjm